# Why is my map not drawing properly?

Tags: opengl, c++

My code compiles fine but for some reason, I get this white background in my window. what am I doing wrong?

I want to draw my map (sorry, there is a lot of code).

Here is my debugged window image:
[image]

Here is my function for drawing my map:

```
void drawmaps()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Textures[0]);
  //suelo
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(15, 0);
  glVertex3f(4, 0, 4);

  glTexCoord2f(15, 15);
  glVertex3f(4, 0, -4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 15);
  glVertex3f(-4, 0, -4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-4, 0, 4);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);




  //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Textures[1]);

  //pared1
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-4, 0, 4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-4, 0, -4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-4, 2, -4);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-4, 2, 4);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //pared3
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(4, 2, 4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(4, 2, -4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(4, 0, -4);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(4, 0, 4);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //pared2
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(4, 0, -4);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(4, 2, -4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-4, 2, -4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-4, 0, -4);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //pared4
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(4, 2, 4);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(4, 0, 4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-4, 0, 4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-4, 2, 4);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);


  //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Textures[3]);

  //techo
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(7, 0);
  glVertex3f(-4, 2, 4);

  glTexCoord2f(7, 7);
  glVertex3f(-4, 2, -4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 7);
  glVertex3f(4, 2, -4);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(4, 2, 4);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);




  //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Textures[2]);

  //columna1A
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 0, 2);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 2, 2);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3, 2, 2);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3, 0, 2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna1B
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3, 0, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3, 2, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 2, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 0, 1.5);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna1C
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 0, 2.00000095367432);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 0, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 2, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 2, 2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna1D
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 2, 2.00000095367432);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 2, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 0, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 0, 2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna2A
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(3, 0, 2);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(3, 2, 2);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(2.5, 2, 2);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(2.5, 0, 2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna2B
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(2.5, 0, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(2.5, 2, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(3, 2, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(3, 0, 1.5);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna2C
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(3.00000023841858, 0, 2.00000095367432);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(3.00000023841858, 0, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(3.00000023841858, 2, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(3.00000023841858, 2, 2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna2D
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(2.50000047683716, 2, 2.00000095367432);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(2.50000047683716, 2, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(2.50000047683716, 0, 1.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(2.50000047683716, 0, 2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna3A
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(3, 0, -2);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(3, 2, -2);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(2.5, 2, -2);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(2.5, 0, -2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna3B
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(2.5, 0, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(2.5, 2, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(3, 2, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(3, 0, -2.5);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna3C
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(3.00000023841858, 0, -1.99999904632568);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(3.00000023841858, 0, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(3.00000023841858, 2, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(3.00000023841858, 2, -2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna3D
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(2.50000047683716, 2, -1.99999904632568);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(2.50000047683716, 2, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(2.50000047683716, 0, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(2.50000047683716, 0, -2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna4A
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 0, -2);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 2, -2);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3, 2, -2);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3, 0, -2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna4B
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3, 0, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3, 2, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 2, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 0, -2.5);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna4C
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 0, -1.99999904632568);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 0, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 2, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 2, -2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //columna4D
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(4, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 2, -1.99999904632568);

  glTexCoord2f(4, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 2, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 0, -2.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 0, -2);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);


  //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Textures[4]);

  //pedestalA
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, 0.800000011920929);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, 0.800000011920929);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-1, 0, 1);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //pedestalB
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, -0.800000011920929);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(1, 0, -1);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-1, 0, -1);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, -0.800000011920929);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //pedestalC
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(1, 0, -1);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, -0.800000011920929);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, 0.800000011920929);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //pedestalD
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, 0.800000011920929);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, -0.800000011920929);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-1, 0, -1);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-1, 0, 1);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //pedestalE
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(5, 0);
  glVertex3f(0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, 0.800000011920929);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, -0.800000011920929);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 5);
  glVertex3f(-0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, -0.800000011920929);

  glTexCoord2f(5, 5);
  glVertex3f(-0.800000011920929, 0.699999988079071, 0.800000011920929);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);


  //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Textures[5]);

  //caja1A
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 0, 3.5);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 0.5, 3.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3, 0.5, 3.5);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3, 0, 3.5);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja1B
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3, 0, 3);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3, 0.5, 3);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 0.5, 3);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 0, 3);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja1C
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 0, 3.50000095367432);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 0, 3);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 0.5, 3);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.49999976158142, 0.5, 3.5);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja1D
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 0.5, 3.50000095367432);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 0.5, 3);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 0, 3);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 0, 3.5);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja1E
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 0.5, 3.50000095367432);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.5, 0.5, 3);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 0.5, 3);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.99999952316284, 0.5, 3.5);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja2A
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-1.79999995231628, 0, 3.70000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-1.79999995231628, 0.5, 3.70000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.29999995231628, 0.5, 3.70000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.29999995231628, 0, 3.70000004768372);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja2B
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.29999995231628, 0, 3.20000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.29999995231628, 0.5, 3.20000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-1.79999995231628, 0.5, 3.20000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-1.79999995231628, 0, 3.20000004768372);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja2C
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-1.7999997138977, 0, 3.70000100135803);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-1.7999997138977, 0, 3.20000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-1.7999997138977, 0.5, 3.20000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-1.7999997138977, 0.5, 3.70000004768372);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja2D
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.29999947547913, 0.5, 3.70000100135803);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.29999947547913, 0.5, 3.20000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.29999947547913, 0, 3.20000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.29999947547913, 0, 3.70000004768372);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja2E
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-1.79999995231628, 0.5, 3.70000100135803);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-1.79999995231628, 0.5, 3.20000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2.29999947547913, 0.5, 3.20000004768372);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2.29999947547913, 0.5, 3.70000004768372);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja3A
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3.29999995231628, 0, 3.79999995231628);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3.29999995231628, 0.5, 3.79999995231628);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3.79999995231628, 0.5, 3.79999995231628);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3.79999995231628, 0, 3.79999995231628);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja3B
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3.79999995231628, 0, 3.29999995231628);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3.79999995231628, 0.5, 3.29999995231628);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3.29999995231628, 0.5, 3.29999995231628);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3.29999995231628, 0, 3.29999995231628);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja3C
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3.2999997138977, 0, 3.8000009059906);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3.2999997138977, 0, 3.29999995231628);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3.2999997138977, 0.5, 3.29999995231628);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3.2999997138977, 0.5, 3.79999995231628);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja3D
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3.79999876022339, 0.5, 3.80000114440918);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3.79999876022339, 0.5, 3.30000019073486);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3.79999876022339, 0, 3.30000019073486);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3.79999876022339, 0, 3.80000019073486);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //caja3E
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3.29999923706055, 0.5, 3.80000114440918);

  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3.29999923706055, 0.5, 3.30000019073486);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-3.79999876022339, 0.5, 3.30000019073486);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-3.79999876022339, 0.5, 3.80000019073486);
  glEnd();
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Here is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)

{

  //Initialise GLUT with command-line parameters. 
  glutInit(&argc, argv);

  //Set Display Mode
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);

  //Set the window size
  glutInitWindowSize(2560, 1080);

  //Set the window position
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);

  //Create the window
  glutCreateWindow("HellBlasters Game");
  // sets the window in fullscreen
  glutFullScreen();

  // display function
  glutDisplayFunc(drawmaps);
  // display idle function
  glutIdleFunc(drawmaps);
  //Enter the GLUT event loop
  glutMainLoop();
  // here we init our handles and start our game up
  while (gameloop == true)
  {
    //EngineInits
    GraphicWindow(); // gets the window handle
    EngineUpdate();  // gets the engine handle
    sectorbarrels(); // gets the barrel handle
    sectorceilings(); // gets the ceiling handle
    sectordoors();    // gets the door handle
    sectorfloors();  // gets the floor handle
    sectorpillars(); // gets the pillar handle
    sectorstairs();  // gets the stair handle
    sectorwalls();   // gets the wall handle
    player();        // gets player handle
    frameperSec();   // gets framepersec handle
    fpscamera();     // gets fpscamera handle
    ShadersDat();    // gets shader handles
    playercheats();  // gets player cheat handles
    renderfloorMath(); // gets math of floor
    renderceilingMath(); // gets math of ceiling
    renderdoorMath();    // gets math of door
    renderbarrelMath();  // gets math of barrel
    renderpillarMath(); // gets math of pillar
    renderstairMath(); // gets math of stair
    renderwallMath(); // gets math of wall
    renderenginemath(); // gets engine math
    renderframepersecMath(); // gets fps math
    renderplayercheatsmath(); // gets cheat math
    renderplayermath(); // gets player math
    rendershadermath(); // gets shader math
    drawbarrelsmath(); // draws barrel polygons
    drawceilingsmath(); // draws ceiling polygons
    drawdoorsmath();    // draws door polygons
    drawenginemath_M(); // draws engine polygons
    drawfloorsmath();   // draws floor polygons
    drawframepersecMath(); // draws framepersec
    drawpillarsmath();     // draws pillar polygons
    drawplayersmath();     // draws player polygons
    drawplayer_m();        // draws player_m polygons
    drawscameramath();     // draws camera polygons
    drawshadermath();    // draws shader Images
    drawstairsmath();   // draws stair polygons
    drawwallsmath();    // draws wall polygons
    maploader();      // loads map data
    system("pause /n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, you should fix that by moving the repetitive function calls into a separate function. As for the actual problem; what's the expected output? Please edit your question and provide an image showing what's actually supposed to be rendered on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a white square because that's what you've told OpenGL to draw. You are drawing a square without a texture and with the colour set to white, so you get a white square.